# How can I access values created from my sql in a seperate javascript file? Is json one of the options?

Tags: node.js, json

I am new to node.js I have sql values created in my reports.js file. When I console.log them the correct info show up. I am trying to access these values in my reports.handlebars and save them in an array so I can use it with google charts. Please no php. Below is my reports.js file:

```
function get_reports(callback) {
  var sql = 'select created_by, count(id) as value from charts group by created_by';
  pool.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
    callback(results);
  });
}

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  get_reports(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).render('reports', {data: data});
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is part of my reports.handlebars:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(obj.value);

      function drawChart() {


        // Create the data table.
        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data2.addColumn('string', 'CreatedBy');
            data2.addColumn('number', 'Awards');
        for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
            data2.addRows([arr[i], arr[i+1]]);
        }
```

I'm trying to access the values that are sent in my js file.

Comment: There are several parts to this. First you have to retrieve the data from the server, by doing a GET request to whatever your URL is. Then you probably have to convert the data from the format produced by `pool.query` into the format required by google charts. Then you have to call google charts. You also said something about handlebars, which I don't understand. Which part of this process are you stuck on?

Comment: Basically I want to get the values that I have from my sql in my report.js file and send it to my other file and save those values in an array. res.status(200).render('reports', {data: data}); from here an save into the array into var obj so I can use it for the google charts.The rest of the page is working. I cut the parts of my code off. How can values in the json from one file be sent to another file and save them as an array?

Comment: You've said that `console.log` shows the correct thing, so I'm guessing that you have succeeded in calling the api, perhaps by typing the URL into a browser or using `curl`. When you do this, what response do you get? I.e. what do you see in the browser window?

Comment: When I use the curls I see the correct values so I know its working. I am trying to send values from my reports.js file to the other file and there convert them to javascript objects. That's what I can't figure out.

Comment: So you want to access the data in the database from javascript running in a browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest is the old way to do it - it should work on all browsers, but will probably take more work for you and isn't standard practice. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API is newer but won't work on all browsers, unless you add a library/shim for it to your project. Other libraries also do the same thing, e.g. http://jquery.com/ (more specifically, https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ ).